# Access SQL - Select only the last sequence

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with an ID and multiple informative columns. Sometimes however, I can have multiple data for an ID, so I added a column called "Sequence". Here is a shortened example:

```
ID      Sequence      Name     Tel       Date        Amount
124     1             Bob      873-4356  2001-02-03  10
124     2             Bob      873-4356  2002-03-12  7
124     3             Bob      873-4351  2006-07-08  24
125     1             John     983-4568  2007-02-01  3
125     2             John     983-4568  2008-02-08  13
126     1             Eric     345-9845  2010-01-01  18
```

So, I would like to obtain only these lines:

```
124     3             Bob      873-4351  2006-07-08  24
125     2             John     983-4568  2008-02-08  13
126     1             Eric     345-9845  2010-01-01  18
```

Anyone could give me a hand on how I could build a SQL query to do this ?

Thanks !

Comment: So for each ID, you want to see the record that has a Sequence number larger than other records with that ID.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the maximum sequence using `group by`.  Then you can use `join` to get only the maximum in the original data.

Assuming your table is called `t`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select id, MAX(sequence) as maxs
      from t
      group by id
     ) tmax
     on t.id = tmax.id and
        t.sequence = tmax.maxs
```